# Joining dataframes by the columns with same names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

df:

```
A      B      C
1      x      1
2      y      2
```

and

df2:

```
A     C      D     E
3     3      x     l
4     4      z     k
```

I want the following:

df_r:

```
A        C
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
```

Note: This is just and example, the answer should be capable of not knowing first hand what are the same columns. i.e. Imagine you have a thousand columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is time to introduce `concat` with `join`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],join='inner',ignore_index =True)
Out[30]: 
   A  C
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
```

Another way using `align`

```
pd.concat(df1.align(df2,join='inner',axis=1),ignore_index =True)
Out[37]: 
   A  C
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
```

---

Both of the methods working for `outer` and `inner` join for merge `index` or `columns`

Comment: Great answer, I like that it is so clean.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz ha happy coding :-)

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz I have updated another method , if you would like to check :-), the only weakness of this , is hard to manage more than 2 dataframe combine together .

Comment: I checked it, I believe that the first method is the best one, since you can have theoretically an unlimited amount of dataframes and it should still work. That is also why I am choosing it as the correct answer, since it works for a lot of scenarios and it is really clean.

Answer (score 2):

Simple with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
cols = set(df.columns).intersection(df2.columns)
pd.concat([df[cols], df2[cols]])
```

---

Also simple with [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df[cols].append(df2[cols])
```

Comment: I mush be more specific. I am talking about thousands of columns, so I do not know the ones that are the same.